# How to dynamically update the name of an array in a Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using Mongoose and would like to be able to dynamically update the Array that includes all the other fields.

In my Schema below, I'd like to be able to modify "dynamic_title" with the right value.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dynamic_title: {
    thumbnail_url: String,
    details: {
      title: String,
      by_statement: String,
      publishers: [String],
      description: {
        type: String,
        value: String,
      },
      publish_date: String,
      series: [String],
      identifiers: {
        amazon: [String],
      },
      languages: [
        {
          key: String,
        },
      ],
      isbn_10: [String],
      isbn_13: [String],
    },
  },
});

export const Book = mongoose.model("book", bookSchema);
```

Here's my index.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import logSymbols from "log-symbols";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { ISBN } from "./models/isbn.js";
import { Book } from "./models/book.js";

const database = 'MONGO_URL';

mongoose.connect(database, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function process() {
  try {
    const isbnData = await ISBN.find().lean();

    for (const doc of isbnData) {
      const id = doc.isbn13;
      const url = `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:${id}&jscmd=details&format=json`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = response.data;

      await Book.insertMany(data);
      console.log(`${logSymbols.success} ${id} processed.`);
    }

    console.log(`${logSymbols.success} All documents processed.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(logSymbols.error, error);
  }
}

process();
```

And finally, here's the type of data I'm trying to insert. Each different piece of data has an "ISBN:" which contains all the other elements, and it's this one I'd like to be able to update. Because otherwise I can't access the data.

[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBVWK.png)

When I try to use a Schema without including the Array, it will return my empty schema.

[Database/Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN9E5.png)